# Upper bound on maximum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. What is an upper bound $M$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{\rm max}\left((A+B)^{\rm T}(A+B)\right)\leq M?
\end{equation}

Comment: How is $A$ and $B$ relevant? Why don't you just substitute $A+B=C$ in your whole question?

Comment: Consider this case: If n=1, then $M=2A^2+2B^2$ is an upper bound.

Comment: $M=2A^2+2B^2$ is a matrix...

Comment: If n=1, then $A,B$ are scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $M =(\sigma_A+\sigma_B)^2$, where $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ are the largest singular values of $A$ and $B$, respectively. This bound is tight when $A$ and $B$ can be mutually diagonalized.

This bound can be proven using the fact that, for any vector $x$,
$$\|Ax\| \leq \sigma_A \|x\|,$$
and likewise for $B$. Then if $v$ is the eigenvector of $(A+B)^T(A+B)$ with largest eigenvalue $\lambda$,
$$\lambda = \|\lambda v\| = \|(A+B)^T(A+B)v\| \leq \|A^TAv\| + \|A^TBv\| + \|B^TAv\| + \|B^TBv\|\leq \sigma_A^2 + 2\sigma_A\sigma_B + \sigma_B^2$$

Comment: Thanks. Seems right. I need to know the process of getting this bound. Can you add some steps? How about $M=2\sigma_A^2+2\sigma_B^2$?

Comment: Thanks. Looks less conservative. How is $\lambda=\|\lambda v\|$? I got the rest.

Comment: Can you possibly answer my other question based on your answer to this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241898/conditions-for-positive-definiteness-matrix-inequality/2242116?noredirect=1#comment4611969_2242116

Comment: @Mohkam7 the magnitude of an eigenvector is arbitrary; might as well take it unit